# enviar radio butons dinamicos por POST correactamente

Tags: php, php7

hola buenas estoy realizando un sistema que anteriormente agenda una Reunión con su datos y marcar con un checkbox los participantes que asistirán a dicha Reunión hasta allí bien los inserta a la bbdd a sus respectivas tablas, el problema viene que después de la Reunión se tiene que hacer un reporte de asistencia o inasistencia de dichos participantes, ya logre mandar a llamar a dichos participantes según la Reunión que se quiera hacer el reporte...

en forma de diseño lo tengo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estuve intentando cambiar los radios button por select pero no logro enviar de forma correcta el array de datos para insertarlos a la `tabla PARTICIPANTES`

actualmente el POST se envia asi:

```
ANGELICA_AMELISA_MUÑOZ_SALINAS: ["1"]
CHRISTIAN_SAMUEL_SAUCEDA_FLORES: ["2"]
acta: "actualizar"
descripcion: (2) ["fg", "fss"]
id_registro: "10"
```

y lo envio asi:

```
 <?php
                                        try {
                                            $sql = "SELECT
                                            CONCAT_WS(' ', t4.nombres, t4.apellidos) AS nombres,
                                            t1.id_persona,
                                            t1.id_participante,
                                            t1.id_estado_participante,
                                            t3.estado,
                                            t1.descripcion,
                                            t2.nombre_reunion,
                                            t5.id_acta
                                        FROM
                                            tbl_participantes t1
                                        LEFT JOIN tbl_reunion t2 ON
                                            t2.id_reunion = t1.id_reunion
                                        LEFT JOIN tbl_estado_participante t3 ON
                                            t3.id_estado = t1.id_estado_participante
                                        LEFT JOIN tbl_personas t4 ON
                                            t4.id_persona = t1.id_persona
                                        LEFT JOIN tbl_acta t5 ON
                                            t5.id_reunion = t1.id_reunion
                                        WHERE
                                            t5.id_acta = $id";
                                            $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
                                        } catch (Exception $e) {
                                            $error = $e->getMessage();
                                            echo $error;
                                        }
                                        
                                        while ($estadoacta = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <label for="">
                                                        <?php echo $estadoacta['nombres']; ?>
                                                    </label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type="radio" id="<?php echo $estadoacta['id_persona']; ?>" name="<?php echo $estadoacta['nombres']; ?>[]" value="1">
                                                    
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type="radio" id="<?php echo $estadoacta['id_persona']; ?>" name="<?php echo $estadoacta['nombres']; ?>[]" value="2">
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type="radio" id="<?php echo $estadoacta['id_persona']; ?>" name="<?php echo $estadoacta['nombres']; ?>[]" value="3">
                                                </td>

                                                <td><textarea name="descripcion[]" id="" cols="10" rows="2"><?php echo $estadoacta['descripcion']; ?></textarea></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        <?php  }  ?>
```

en el value lo puse fijo porque al recibir 1 por post en la `tabla PARTICIPANTES` significa que asistio  2 inasistencia y 3 excusa.

se que lo estoy haciendo mal pero no se como hacerlo he estado intentando por muchas horas y nada no se si habria otra manera de hacerlo mas facil

Comment: Como envias los datos por POST?

Comment: No comprendí tu pregunta o el problema que tienes

Comment: obtener de manera correcta el array de los radios porque actualmente los recibo asi  ANGELICA_AMELISA_MUÑOZ_SALINAS: ["1"]
CHRISTIAN_SAMUEL_SAUCEDA_FLORES: ["2"]  y creo que los nombre están mal, porque en realidad son como 40 personas (el ejemplo que postee solo añadi dos participante)

Comment: Probablemente se solucione si quitás los corchetes del `name` de los radiobuttons. Aunque no está muy claro el problema. Podrías mostrar la salida de `var_dump($_POST)` en vez de ese formato personalizado, para que se entienda mejor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu formulario debes mandar los ids de cada persona en un input oculto

por ejemplo

```
<input type="hidden" name="id_persona[]" value="<?php echo $estadoacta['id_persona'] ?>">
```

De esta manera al recibir post todos los arrays te van a llegar con la misma cantidad de elementos , para la primera persona, agarras el indice 0 de todos los arrays, para la información de la segunda, agarras la posicion 1 de todos los arrays y así sucesivamente

Y al recibirlos solo haces esto

```
$id_persona = $_POST["id_persona"];
$estado = $_POST["estado"];
$descripcion = $_POST["descripcion"];
```

Luego puedes recorrer el bucle por el arrays de id_persona

```
foreach($id_persona as key => $persona){
 $id_persona = $id_persona[$key];
 $estado = $estado[$key];
 $descripcion = $descripcion[$key];

 //Codigo para insertar cada fila de cada persona.....
```

}

Y de esa manera ya tienes los datos que le corresponden a cada persona

Comment: es que al poner en el *name="estado[]"* no me deja seleccionar el segundo, tercero,cuarto participante la seleccion del de arriba se trasporta para el que selecciono

Comment: Tienes razón, habia entendido mal, pero en el name no le pongas el nombre de la persona,sino manejalo con su id , y luego como en el for tendrás cada id de la persona , desde dentro del mismo for obtienes su valor , asi, $_POST[$id_persona[$key]]

Comment: el input hidden donde iría

Comment: Dentro del bucle , con el id de la persona